# when I clear the APP cache the automatic login doesn't work

Tags: android

it happens to the stranger when I install the APP, the login with Shardprefereces works fine, but if I clean the cache, the login no longer works, it shows me the stored data but it does not start, now I desist and I reinstall and it works, any idea that it might be

the Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

before adding the permissions everything worked fine, now it gives me that problem

Comment: AFAIK, shared preferences won't clear when u clean caches. It only gone when you clear app data.

Comment: That is the problem, I just realized, it is when I delete the data, if the user arrives and deletes the data, and put his username and password again, and then close the APP, he no longer automatically logs in, he has to place your data again